# Rails 3 Render Prawn pdf in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, prawn

How to render prawn pdf as attachment in ActionMailer? I use delayed_job and don't understand, how could I render pdf-file in action mailer (not in controller). What format should I use?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to tell Prawn to render the PDF to a string, and then add that as an attachment to the email.  See the [ActionMailer docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) for details on attachments.

Here's an example:

```
class ReportPdf
  def initialize(report)
    @report = report
  end

  def render
    doc = Prawn::Document.new

    # Draw some stuff...
    doc.draw_text @report.title, :at => [100, 100], :size => 32

    # Return the PDF, rendered to a string
    doc.render
  end
end

class MyPdfMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def report(report_id, recipient_email)
    report = Report.find(report_id)

    report_pdf_view = ReportPdf.new(report)

    report_pdf_content = report_pdf_view.render()

    attachments['report.pdf'] = {
      mime_type: 'application/pdf',
      content: report_pdf_content
    }
    mail(:to => recipient_email, :subject => "Your report is attached")
  end
end
```

Comment: I already have views/invoices/show.pdf.prawn. InvoicesController renders it successfully. I tried to render it using render_to_string in mailer and got corrupt PDF. How to render this existing view file? May be I need to specify :type or format for render_to_string.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the RailsCasts for [PRAWN](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised). Taken what has already been said and what I was trying to similarly accomplish, I set the attachment name and then created the PDF.

InvoiceMailer:

```
 def invoice_email(invoice)
    @invoice = invoice
    @user = @invoice.user
    attachments["#{@invoice.id}.pdf"] = InvoicePdf.new(@invoice, view_context).render
    mail(:to => @invoice.user.email,
         :subject => "Invoice # #{@invoice.id}")
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
render_to_string('invoices/show.pdf', :type => :prawn)
```

PDF was corrupted because I didn't write block for mail function and multi-part email was incorrect.

Comment: This solution doesn't work in Rails 5.x I get `undefined method `response' for #<PicksheetMailer:0x007fcfa506f258>
Did you mean?  response_body' when I tried to render a prawn template using `    attachments["customer_order_#{@order.order_number}.pdf"] = render_to_string('picksheet/send_picksheet.pdf', :type => :prawn)`

So it seems that prawn is expecting to write to a `response` which doesn't exist inside ActionMailer