# render pdf using prawn as an actionmailer attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, actionmailer, prawn

Context: Why am I sending a pdf via email? Because I'm trying to send it to a HP printer in an office from a Rails app running on AWS. I can send pdf attachments to an email address provided by HP and it prints on the printer. It has to be an attachment, it can't be inline.

Stack: Rails 5.0.2, OSX for development, Ubuntu 16.04 for production

Problem: I have a Prawn template that generates the PDF, it works fine when called inside an ActionController, but fails inside an ActionMailer.

From this Stackoverflow question [Rails 3 Render Prawn pdf in ActionMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467989/rails-3-render-prawn-pdf-in-actionmailer) I tried

`attachments["customer_order_#{@order.order_number}.pdf"] = render_to_string('picksheet/send_picksheet.pdf', :type => :prawn)`

and got this error `undefined method "response" for #<PicksheetMailer:0x007fcfa506f258>
Did you mean?  response_body`

So the answer worked in Rails 3 but doesn't in Rails 5. The error occurs on the first line in the prawn template where it's generating output. So I looks like it's trying to write into `response` which exists inside ActionController, but not ActionMailer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You might give this a shot. It uses wicked_pdf instead of prawn but it seems quite simple to setup. https://berislavbabic.com/send-pdf-attachments-from-rails-with-wickedpdf-and-actionmailer/